# How to sort list of string based on custom logic in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an arraylist with values ... ST1000, ST 5000, ST 30000, ST400, ST500, SP1000, SP600

I want it o be sorted like ST1000, ST2000, ST3000, ST4000, SP600, SP1000 .. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: what are the values? Some kind of objects? Can you please post the code that you have written?

Comment: @OlimpiuPOP - No it is just string values!

Comment: My code doesnt have any sorting yet, if it would have been objects, i thought of using comparator but its just string values :(

Comment: Put them in an array or list and use respective sort method with custom comparator

Comment: it should be possible to use [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-). The big question is now how do you want to sort it

Comment: As `ST4000, SP600` are not in sorted in natural order. What are the sorting rules?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `compareTo` which will compare it for you lexicographically

here are 2 methods to sort your list using java 8

```
list.stream()
    .sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2)).collect(Collectors.toList());

list.sort((s1, s2)->s1.compareTo(s2));
```

using java 8, you don't have to use Collections.sort method

Answer (score 0):

You can sort any collection in a desired manner with a [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method.

All you need to do is to realize `Comparator's` `compare` method accordingly.

In your particular case it would go something like this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ST1000", "ST5000", "ST30000", "ST400", "ST500", "SP1000", "SP600");
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String o1Prefix = o1.substring(0, 2);
        String o2Prefix = o2.substring(0, 2);
        if (o1Prefix.equals(o2Prefix)) {
            return Integer.parseInt(o1.substring(2, o1.length())) > Integer.parseInt(o2.substring(2, o2.length())) ? 1 : -1;
        } else if (o1Prefix.equals("ST")) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can create a custom Comparator object and override compare method with the desired logic.

```
Comparator<Model> customComparator = new Comparator<Model>() {

        public int compare(Model arg0, Model arg1) {
            //TODO custom sort logic
         }

       };
```

if compare returns -1 then the arg0 is less than arg1 , 0 equals and 1 greater

then sort the list using the custom comparator

```
         Collections.sort(list, customComparator);
```